# GRUB doesn't react to USB keyboard, it did before

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, usb, keyboard

I've installed Ubuntu about two weeks earlier, it works fine(although a bit slow, probably not enough space), the PC boots up, there is the BIOS... then the GRUB, i select either Windows 10 or Ubuntu(Ubuntu is at the top), then it boots up just as well as before.
Today I turned on my computer, I forgot to change the GRUB selection because I was dressing, so I stopped my PC by Ubuntu's stop button. Started it up again, I wanted to select Windows, but GRUB just doesn't react to anything. BIOS works, Ubuntu works(as I am here), but GRUB is just dead to anything. It did not happened before. I always shut down my PC in the "legit" way. As the tags say, USB keyboard and mouse. It wasn't happening before. If you need any more information, please comment!

Edit: Managed to solve it, check your BIOS for settings about keyboard or inputs, there is something there.

Answer (score 0):

lmao I cant login due to Microsoft's generous browser, so this guest thing will work. As said, I managed to boot, I just had to change almost every setting, I did not find anything related to keyboard, so, if you are having this issue, please check out the settings in the bios, probably helps you out. btw moderators pls mark this question as answered ty
another btw i did tried logging in again lol it just doesnt let me use fb

Comment: Please re-write you answer to more informative as to how you solved the issue, as for __marking__ its up to you after a few minutes of posting the answer...

Comment: Im just an idiot, i still have ubuntu to use my account... xd okay basically i dont know how did i solved, as said in the answer i changed a lot of settings maybe one of them solves it. sorry for so much misunderstanding in askubuntu.com i was very frustated about that